# Cakephp : $this->Thumb->show() not work on live server

Tags: cakephp, image-resizing, jcarousel

I am using **cakephp version 2.5.5** and i want to resize image at display time, for this i am using $this->Thumb->show() from **phpThumb**, it work fine only at localhost not on live server

```
$this->Thumb->show(
                                    array('save_path' => ROOT . '/app/webroot/img/advertisements/',
                                            'display_path' => Router::url('/',true).'img/advertisements/',
                                            'error_image_path' => Router::url('/',true).'img/advertisements/Image-Not-Available.jpg',
                                            'src' => ROOT.'/app/webroot/img/advertisements/'.$value['name'],
                                            'w' => 674,
                                            'h' => 420,
                                            'q' => 100,
                                            'zc' => 1
                                    )

                                );
```

Actually i am using the jcarousel slider which show image 3 at a time, for this image should be in same ratio so i need resize image to show slider

Localhost image slider 
[image]

Live Server image slider
[image]

Please help its very usrgent, Thanks in advance

Comment: On local all image are resize in 674 * 420, but on live they resize in diffrent ration

Comment: Nothing find in source code, rest are updated

Comment: How is your completely blank html page rendering anything then? I don't know how you expect anyone to be able to help you from 2 screenshots and no relevant code, your problem is primarily html (unless you demonstrate to the contrary), you need to identify the html-cause first before looking at your php code.

Comment: @AD7six thanks. i am check

Comment: You have any other idea about to resize the image when it display on browser and images are coming in loop :)